# Was this theme from Lohengrin ever used for a Superman show?

Tags: superman

I have a mental association between the [Prelude to Act III of Lohengrin by Richard Wagner](https://youtu.be/ZOQlG8YRxEQ?t=25) (particularly the horns which come in at 0:25 in the linked YouTube) and the George Reeves Superman shows, as if some of the episodes used that theme at some point. The clips I've found on-line have different theme music (presumably specifically written for the show).

My question: did any of the 1950s Superman shows ever use the Wagner theme?

My childhood introduction to Superman was via a kid's show which ran in the mid-late 1960s on WKBW (Buffalo, New York) called "Commander Tom". Could my memory of the theme come from the way they presented the Superman shows?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventures_of_Superman_(TV_series)#Music has no mention except to say a lot of stock/library music. As Wagner has been out of copyright since noah was wondering if it might rain, there would have been nothing to stop them.